# Rails3 integration test with array parameters or parameter arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do some Rails integration testing.

I have a case almost right out of the Rails guide on form helpers.

My HTML contains:

```
    <input name="to_org[][str2int]" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <input name="to_org[][str2int]" value="2" type="checkbox">
    <input name="to_org[][str2int]" value="3" type="checkbox">
```

The application works fine with Rails 3.2.2.

Now I want to write an integration test. I need to post the the data the
same way my JavaScript does. I'd like to indicate "to_org[]" values 1 and
2 are selected. Assume form_url is a properly set value.

```
    post( form_url, { "to_org[][str2int]" => ???WHAT_GOES_HERE??? } )
```

After the post, I'm expecting params to hold:

```
    "to_org" => [ {"str2int" => "1"}, {"str2int" => "2"} ]
```

I've tried a bunch of different things, looked through the guides, googled.

Hasn't anyone tried to post the result of multiple checkboxes being
checked? I don't think the answer is obvious.

How does one set the parameters for post() in integration test to make
this work?

PS: As one might guess, I have a filter that recognizes "str2int", and
does the conversion with appropriate checking and error recovery for the
app. Eventually my app sees :to_org = [ 1, 2 ].

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I did some digging through the rails code (would be nice to
see it make the API documentation.)

A right answer is:

```
    post( form_url, { "to_org" => [ { "str2int" => "1" }, { "str2int" => "2" } ] } )
```

Most helpful was discovering the to_param() function, as in:

```
    { "to_org" => [ { "str2int" => "1" }, { "str2int" => "2" } ] }.to_param()
```

This allowed me to deduce the fact that I had to vary what I used as the
name to get the values passed thru post() correctly.

Rails gods: Is there a better way to do this? More that should be said?